# Do full postback in update panel in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

how do i do full postback although the button is "inside" UpdatePanel using JavaScript?

**note that i don't have access permission to the server side or the .aspx files.**

Comment: But i need that the server do the functionality of the specific button.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="button" id="Button45" name="Button45" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('ButtonA','')" value="clicking this will run ButtonA.Click Event Handler" /><br /><br />
```

works?